# Backpropagation after N sequential input-output pass

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a Neural Network in a particular situation -- similar to a genetic algorithm domain as far as I know.
I have to run a simulation with a length of $K$ steps.
I have a neural network $N$ that at each time step is used to produce an output, so that:
$$
o_{t+1} = N(i_{t})
$$
$i_t$ is a feature vector built upon $o_{t-1}$, and $i_0$ is given.
My ground-truth value is $o_k$, namely the right value at the end of the simulation. So, I can evaluate the loss (e.g. MSE) only at the end of the simulation.
Suppose to fix k to 3, the evaluation is: $N(N(N(i_0))$
because:
$$
o_1 = N(i_o) \\
o_2 = N(i_1) \\
o_3 = N(i_2)
$$
So my questions are:

- does it have any sense to apply backpropagation in these settings?
- if yes, what happens to the gradients?

Practically, in some simple situations, the backpropagation seems to work, but in others, the gradients explode or vanishes

Comment: Is it possible that you could train it in steps, starting from short simulations and then working up to longer ones?

Comment: In some case it is possible, but in the general case no..

Answer (score 1):

### I/ Does it has any sense to apply backpropagation in these settings?

If I understand correctly, this question should be "Can backpropagation return the gradient for every node of these networks?".

It depends on your network $N$ if it is differentiable with all inputs $i_t$ so the backpropagation can be guaranteed that there are the gradient values at every node of the network.

### II/ If yes, what happens to the gradients?

We deal with the vanishing or exploding gradient after we make sure that the gradient is **exist**. The reason for this phenomenon in a neural network can come various, some typical causes are:

1. Very deep neural networks (a large number of layers):

   Assume a neural network with $n$-th layers, the backpropagation is followed the Markov Chain's rule can be show as:

$$\frac{\partial loss}{\partial w_t} = \frac{\partial loss}{\partial l_{n}} \times \frac{\partial l_{n}}{\partial l_{n-1}}\times...\times \frac{\partial l_{t+1}}{\partial l_{t}}\times \frac{\partial l_t}{\partial w_t}$$

It's easy to see that the gradient is scaled exponentially for each layer, so if each gradient value is larger than 1, the gradient will become $\inf$ with $n\rightarrow \inf$ (exploding) and $0$ in vice versa.

2. Activation function:

   The image below shows the difference between different activation functions. It's easy to see that the logistic function such as Sigmoid or Tanh is limited in the range $[0,1]$ (in case sigmoid) or $[-1,1]$ in case Tanh. Therefore, if the output from a node of the neural network is larger than 2 or smaller than -2, the gradient will become nearly zero (vanishing) because the output is always the same.

[image: activation function]

Solution:

- Replace it by the simple function such as ReLU: $o_{t+1} = max(0, N(i_t))$. However, the output from ReLU will be $0$ if it's lower than $0$, so there are many variants of ReLU to solve this problem, you can find them easily by the keyword "ReLU family" on google ([example](https://www.jefkine.com/deep/2016/08/08/initialization-of-deep-networks-case-of-rectifiers/)).

There are other methods or strategies to duel with vanishing/exploding gradient, it also depends on your model or your data. The answer can be more detailed if you give more information.